# App-enginee project suddenly showing red underlines in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an app-engine Google cloud endpoint project whose source that I have not opened in about eight months. Today I opened the source to find a bunch of eclipse red underscore all over the place. I am not sure why it's doing that. Does anyone know what the problem might be? All my endpoint annotations have red underline. Example

```
@Api(
    name = "...",
    namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = "…", ownerName = "...", packagePath = ""),
    version = "v1",
    description = "...",
    defaultVersion = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)
```

and ApiMethod, name, and httpMethod in the following

```
@ApiMethod(name = "registerUser", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
```

I built the project using java 6. But I don't think that should affect my annotations? Does anyone know what I can do to restore my project to a working state?

I understand the wrong question may get me the wrong answer, but I am at a lost on how else to ask this. My eclipse is up-to-date, my app-engine is up-to-date, etc. I must definitely have missed something. I just don't know what.

An important note: The actual project is on app-engine and is working fine. I am just deciding to add a few more features to the project, and that's how I find all the red underlines in my local (and only) source.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems occasionally and no clear solution.  A laborious way forward is to create a new project with a fresh Eclipse and Java 7, and to gradually import all your existing code into it.  Java 6 is no longer supported by AppEngine.